# Backtracking algorithm to maximize number of boxes in two rooms

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, backtracking

We have two rooms of certain sizes(lets call it volume). We have a number of boxes that we have to fit in the two rooms. The boxes have certain sizes, and we cannot stack any boxes on top of each other. Our goal is to maximize the number of boxes in the two rooms using backtracking algorithm. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Given that you can't stack the boxes, this is a [two-dimensional bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Packing_in_2-dimensional_containers). So the rooms don't have volume, they have floor **area**. And each box that needs to fit in the rooms has an area that it occupies on the floor. You also need to specify whether the boxes can be rotated by angles that aren't multiples of 90 degrees, [as in this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:10_kvadratoj_en_kvadrato.svg).

Comment: @user3386109 no we cannot rotate the boxes. What is the best way to solve such problems?

Answer (score 0):

I guess my suggestion would be to think of this as a searching problem in a tree or graph structure. What you need to do is continue to try different paths and save the "best solution". However, this could end up trying all of the possibilies and be O(n!). Therefore, I advise you use some sort of pruning or logic so that this isn't the case. i.e. Alpha-Beta or don't persue paths once they exceed some specifications.